# How to fit content on remaining height

Tags: jquery, html, css

i need to create a responsive website which will fit content inside a browser height and should not display a vertical scroll. I need to place header at the top of the page and footer at the bottom, and i need to place content in the remaining height. Inside a content i had an image which must fit in that content and must not scale. Is there any solution to do that, or i need to calculate header height and then header footer and to subtract with window height. Thank you :)

```
var content = $(window).height() - $('.header').height() - $('.footer').height();
```

Comment: You could set the height for header, footer and content in percentage.

Comment: and `overflow: hidden` on the content I guess

Comment: I have fixed header and footer height, i can't do that. Is there any other way to do that :)

Answer (score 0):

**Js:**

```
function _responsive( )
{
    var content = $(window).height() - $('.header').height() - $('.footer').height();
    $('.content').css('height' , content);
}
$(window).resize(function()
{
    _responsive();
});
_responsive();
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.content {
    overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:auto;
}
```

Comment: Just wondering, why do you have `_` before the function name?

Comment: @DanielLisik My convention, if you wrap this into an class, this will present a private function.

Comment: Welcome, some developers use double underscore to present private function.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a fixed header a footer, try something like this. I'm not sure if this is any more practical than just using javascript, but here goes

html..

```
<body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</body>
```

css...

```
body {
    overflow:hidden;
}
#header {
    background-color:blue;
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0%;
    z-index:1;
}
#content {
    background-color:red;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
    z-index:0;
}
#footer {
    background-color:green;
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    position:relative;
    top:-100px;
    z-index:1;
}
```

set the top of the footer to the negative height of the footer.

Comment: OP said he had fixed height on header and footer.

Comment: I have a fixed header and footer, i cannot use the percentage on this two :(

Comment: i edited, its semi-working with just html and css, but it would probably just make sense to go with javascript either way.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Since you have fixed height for the header and footer you can do this:

```
var _UI = function() {
            var w = $(window).height();
            var h = 100; //height of your header
            var f = 300; //height of your footer
            $('#content-div').css({'height': (w - (h - f)) + 'px'});
        };
```

after creating this func that will store the right height size you just need to call it on window.resize and doc.ready

```
        $(window).resize(function() {
            _UI();
        });

        $(document).ready(function() {
            _UI();
        });
```

Comment: `height:100;` on body? Shouldn't it be `100%`?

Comment: I have a fixed header and footer so i can't use percentage on this two  :(

Comment: @EdonBajrami what about this?

Comment: If you check my solution is the same that i have, thnx for your reply :)